Replacing sloped roof with straight roof
I am considering purchasing a house in Romania. The house has a structure of reinforced concrete pillars and beams, and the walls are made of brick (solid brick on the ground floor, and porothermic brick on the first floor). House was build around 10 years ago.
The problem is there are 2 rooms (pictures attached) that have mansard roof in convex shape (so the central part of the roof is straight and the edges are sloped) and very small windows due to that. Essentially half of the room has the ceiling decreasing from 2.5m to 1.5 m, which I absolutely don't like and is very impractical. The other half of the room and the hallway has straight ceiling and roof with good height. How difficult and risky is to remove at all the sloped roof and make it straight? How long does that take (it's about 15 square meters of sloped roof)? Can I have only the sloped roof removed without needing to modify the straight roof? Also, how much would that cost? For reference the whole 120 square meters house is 140k, would 10k be enough for this project?
I understand that before starting any work I need to consult an architect, construction engineer, building team and so on but I just want to understand how big this project is before actually deciding to purchase.
Thank you!

No pics attached. If you can't edit them in yourself, upload them somewhere like imgur and someone else here will edit them in.

With this level of detail, it's a large and expensive project. You would be ripping the roof off of at least part of your house with all the attendant issues of weather while the roof is removed causing problems, etc. Also, merely putting a roof up in the first place is a major project, much less trying to put one up that has to interface with an exsisting one, and changes in structure that may be required to support it, etc. Selling the house and buying a different house might well be more practical. Or simply not buying it, since you say you are "considering purchase."

When you revise to add your photos, replace "straight" with "level". You'll be much more clear. Technically, all your ceiling planes are straight.

No, you can't (practically speaking) square out the sloped portions of your ceiling. A roof needs an exterior slope, and the reason you have a mansard roof is to reduce the overall height of the structure. If there wasn't a geometric need for those interior slopes, they wouldn't have been created.
In order to have a level ceiling across the entire room, the walls need to be extended and the existing roof needs to be raised at the ridge. This is essentially a complete rebuild of the roof.
